# Send sequence of keys to Node js

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js and trying to send a number to my Node js function and have it enter in my test. I am using the following function

```
navigateToNumber : function(NumberString){
    NumberString = NumberString.toString();
    var chNum = NumberString.split("");
    for(var i=0 ; i < chNum.length ; i++){
        browser.keys(chNum[i]);
    }
```

What i am trying to achieve here is if my input is 45, it should enter 45. However sometimes it enters 45 and sometimes it enter 4 and 5 individually. How do I time this in such a way that it enters 45 ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what I was doing wrong. I changed the below code to

```
navigateToNumber : function(NumberString){
     NumberString = NumberString.toString();
     var chNum = NumberString.split("");
     browser.keys(chNum);
}
```

and it worked.